# How to upload file to Confluence on scheduled basis?

Tags: confluence

We use confluence as project(s) wiki etc.

There are plenty of useful docs, tables, etc. But many of them can be actual one day and not actual next day.

So, it will be just perfect to use/(implement?) feature, which will re-upload needed file(s) in confluence by schedule. Files will be (for example) get from git repository.

So, my question is: Does confluence have such feature ((re)uploading files by schedule)? If not, is there any way to implement this, except of new plugin writing?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a CI server (like Jenkins), you can create a nightly job to upload the new version of the docs using the [Confluence REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/).

Extract from the doc:

```
A simple example to upload a file called "myfile.txt" to the Attachment with id "456" in a container with id "123", with the comment updated, and minorEdit set to true:
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" -F "minorEdit=true" -F "comment=This
                  is my updated File" http://myhost/rest/api/content/123/child/attachment/456/data
```